# Cursor does not work listview

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have this method to populate a listview

```
private void llenarLista() {
    SQLiteDatabase bd= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SuperStock/SuperStock.db", null, 0);
    Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("select _id, cod_cliente, nom_cliente, fecha, estado_envio,estado, total_final from pedidos where estado_envio='pendiente' ORDER BY fecha DESC", null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        adaptador = new AdaptadorListaPedidos(ConsultarPedidos2.this, cursor);
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }
    else
        mensaje("Linea 66","cursor vacio");

    cursor.close();
    bd.close();
}
```

but I have problems with the cursor, when you run cursor.close () the list is empty, and when commented that //cursor.close line (), the list is displayed populated. I'm misusing the cursor? Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `close()` a `Cursor` while it is in use by a `CursorAdapter`. Please:

- Open your database *once*, on a background thread
- Run your query on a background thread, perhaps the same thread that opened your database
- Close the cursor when you are done with the `CursorAdapter`, such as in `onDestroy()` of the activity or fragment that is hosting the `ListView`
- Close the database, if practical, when you are done with the database (which, by definition, is sometime after you are done with the `Cursor` that you got from the database)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. @CommonsWare please I have further questions point to conduct consultations on a background thread. As I do for a return asynctaks me a Cursor? , To work with and to reuse the same thread background for all of this activity querys. it does not seem practical called a AsyncTask for each query. Sorry for my bad English and I hope you can help me finish to understand the use of the cursor